# 'If' statement in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There is an online feed available in the following format in the link 
http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/cycle-hire/livecyclehireupdates.xml

Using D3 i am plotting a circle, on a map of London, wherever these stations are located. I want to implement the following. If the number of bikes (given as nbBikes in the XML file) are  less than 5 the "fill" of the circle should be red else green. 
I got the circles rightly plotted but the IF statement is not working.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:56854/WebForm1.aspx?webURL=http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/cycle-hire/livecyclehireupdates.xml",
            dataType: 'xml', 
            data: data,
            success: parseXml,
            error: MyMessage
        });

        function parseXml(data) {
            var stations = d3.select(data).selectAll("station")[0];
            g.selectAll("circle")
                   .data(stations)
                   .enter()
                   .append("circle")
                   .attr("r", 3)
                   .style("fill", function (d) {            // 
                       if (d.getElementsByTagName("nbBikes").childNodes[0].nodeValue <= 5) { return "red" }  // 
                     else { return "black" }          // 
                     ;
                 })
                   .attr("cx", function (d) {
                       return projection([d.getElementsByTagName("long")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, d.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue])[0];
                   }) 
                   .attr("cy", function (d) {
                       return projection([d.getElementsByTagName("long")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, d.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue])[1];
                   })
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do in your code. You may want to start with [a simple tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/).

Comment: This may also be of use: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/

Comment: Should it be `d.getElementsByTagName("nbBikes")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue`?